# textedit wont display when called from another class

Tags: c++, qt

Set up this funciton in mainwindow class, but when calling from another class wont output to textedit screen. I can call it from the main.cpp and it works but when calling from another class, by setting object, it wont output to textedit, also the textedit is set as readonyl but that shouldnt be affecting anything

```
void MainWindow::output(QString y) {
    ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(y);
    ui->textEdit->insertPlainText("\n");
}
```

EDIT: called like this

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
```

later

```
 MainWindow window4;
    window4.output("You are now a ranger, a master with a bow. You start with a basic bow and some simple archery lessons");
```

Comment: Show how you're calling it. You sure you're calling it on the correct MainWindow instance?

Comment: `textedit is set as readonyl but that shouldnt be affecting anything` -> Editing a readonly field should be affecting anything?!

Comment: well idk im new to this, thats why i ask questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating a new object of MainWindow in your other class. You should have a pointer to your MainWindow object from the main like:

```
MainWindow * window4;
```

And call output like:

```
window4->output("You are now a ranger, a master with a bow. You start with a basic bow and some simple archery lessons");
```

Also don't forget to assign the pointer in the main:

```
MainWindow w;
myCustomClass.window4 = &w;
```

Comment: Why cant i create a new object? also how would i access the pointer in the main from my custom class?

Comment: I cant seem to store the object in a pointer, heresthe code `MainWindow w;` `int *wptr;`  `wptr = &w;`

Comment: Figured it out, Thanks!